# Is it possible create this text effect?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

was wondering if it is possible to recreate this text effect in Blender. I've been playing around but nothing is coming close enough. Can't figure things out like the bevel, perspective, & material. If anyone can help guide me to get closer it'd be much appreciated, thanks.

[image: FTW]

[image: SUPREME]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure people here are able to tell you how to precisely tweak the various settings to get something that looks good to you.  But in general you could use the following techniques to get the result below:

[image]

Choosing a suitable font is your call.  To give it thickness, use the Extrude setting under Geometry-Modification in the Font tab of the Properties window.  To give it a bevel, choose the Depth setting under Geometry-Bevel.

[image]

To curve the text, one way to do it is using the Mesh Deform modifier.  Here I've used it with a subdivided cube:

[image]

Finally, the material and textures are really going to be an aesthetic choice by you. I will however show you a quick way to texture different faces of the object differently even while it's still a text object:

[image]