# Deforming text maintaining vertical alignment

Tags: modeling, text-object

I would like to deform my text to fit along a curve, but maintain a vertical alignment like in the picture.

Any help would be a big help! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I align a text object to curve without deformation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32383/how-can-i-align-a-text-object-to-curve-without-deformation)

Comment: If you are new please search before posting. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41967/wrap-text-around-a-circle-without-deforming-it-numbers-on-clock/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80298/how-to-add-numbers-to-a-dial/ or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101157/is-it-possible-create-this-text-effect/ and

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos the proposed duplicate does not keep the vertical alignment. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCcty.png

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [**Lattice**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/lattice.html?highlight=lattice) and [**Proportional Editing**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/layout.html#proportional-editing)

Add a lattice object and scale it so that it covers your object. 
Make the number on the U axis an odd number so that you have a division in the middle.

[image]

Select the Text Object and add a [**Lattice Modifier**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/lattice.html?highlight=lattice). Assign the newly created lattice as the deform object.

[image]

Select the lattice, enter edit mode, select the vertices in the middle.

Enable Proportional editing and set the falloff type to "sphere"

Press <kbd>G</kbd> (to move the selected vertices) and use the scroll wheel on the mouse to adjust the influence of the proportional edit, so that the circle covers the whole text.

Move the vertices up.

[image]

Comment: That's the ticket! Thanks a bunch... this site is VERY helpful!!